# Missing line breaks in cells after importing Excel spreadsheet into Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, excel, pandas, import, line-breaks

I'm using Python Pandas to import an Excel spreadsheet (**xlsx**) into a dataframe. The Excel spreadsheet contains text in some columns. An example cell with multiline text is given below:

```
document belongs to family 13: 
claims are important. 
description discloses a bycicle with 3 wheels.
assigne is well known Trudi Bikes Inc.
```

The cells contain line breaks. The example has 4 lines. The problem is that the line breaks get lost when importing the spread into the dataframe. All lines are merged into one line.

As far as I know Excel adds line breaks with a special character CHR(10) or the like.

My question therefore: *is there a way of keeping this special characters when importing a spreadsheet (or the line break) into a pandas data frame?* I wouldn't mind having something like escape sequence in the string of the dataframe cell.

Regards,

Vinz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this way I keep the `\n` in the df:

```
 df = pd.read_excel(yourfile, 'Sheet1')
```

[image]

Output:

```
                 col1     col2      col3
0  hello\ncome in\ngo    hello        hi
1                 bye  bye bye  bye\nbye
```

Comment: Hi Joe, thanks for your feedback. I am able to reproduce your results. It helps to proceed. In my tests I have printed single cells through df.iloc with the consequence that the \n are not printed. And in further wrangling the data I lost the line breaks completely. Thanks! Vinz

Comment: @VinzFrauchiger You are welcome. If the answer helped you, please consider to upvote and accept it :)